# Group rows with missing values in each row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have got a table in SQL Server 2008 looking like this

```
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4
-------------------------------
TEST1 ;AAAAAA;NULL  ;NULL
TEST1 ;NULL  ;BBBBBB;NULL
TEST1 ;NULL  ;NULL  ;CCCC
TEST2 ;XXXXXX;NULL  ;NULL
TEST2 ;NULL  ;YYYYYY;NULL
TEST2 ;NULL  ;NULL  ;ZZZZ
TEST3 ;UUUUUU;VVVVVV;NULL
```

and I want a result like this:

```
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4
TEST1 ;AAAAAA;BBBBBB;CCCC
TEST2 ;XXXXXX;YYYYYY;ZZZZ
TEST3 ;UUUUUU;VVVVVV;NULL
```

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compress rows with nulls and duplicates into single rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923776/compress-rows-with-nulls-and-duplicates-into-single-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way do achieve it is to use subqueries on the select.

```
declare @MyTable table
(
    FIELD1 varchar(50)
   ,FIELD2 varchar(50)
   ,FIELD3 varchar(50)
   ,FIELD4 varchar(50)
)

insert into @MyTable values
('TEST1', 'AAAAAA', NULL    , NULL)
,('TEST1', NULL    , 'BBBBBB', NULL)
,('TEST1', NULL    , NULL    , 'CCCC')
,('TEST2', 'XXXXXX', NULL    , NULL)
,('TEST2', NULL    ,'YYYYYY', NULL)
,('TEST2', NULL    ,NULL    ,'ZZZZ')
,('TEST3', 'UUUUUU','VVVVVV', NULL)

select * from @MyTable t0


select t1.FIELD1
, (select top 1 t2.FIELD2 from @MyTable t2 where t2.FIELD2 is not null and t2.FIELD1 = t1.Field1)
, (select top 1 t3.FIELD3 from @MyTable t3 where t3.FIELD3 is not null and t3.FIELD1 = t1.Field1)
, (select top 1 t4.FIELD4 from @MyTable t4 where t4.FIELD4 is not null and t4.FIELD1 = t1.Field1)
 from @MyTable t1
  group by t1.FIELD1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this returns exactly what I need. What if I have 30 fields and ~1mio rows. Wouldn't all the subselects make this really unperformant? Would this be better than the join solution in the other solution?

Comment: The most performatic? depends a lot of your schema, idexes, etc. Only an acid test can tell for sure. But since i'm using top in that subqueries I suspect it's better than a outter join. For 30+ fields maybe loop can do better, just putting the right logic and iterating over that table just once per row

Answer (score 0):

static solution is here:

```
SELECT a.FIELD1,a.FIELD2,b.FIELD3,c.FIELD4
FROM YourTable a
LEFT JOIN YourTable b ON a.FIELD1 = b.FIELD1 AND b.FIELD3 IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN YourTable c ON a.FIELD1 = c.FIELD1 AND c.FIELD4 IS NOT NULL
WHERE a.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately it ill not work when there aren't a non null value for field2, also it can multiply rows if there are two not null on the same field2-4 for the same field1

Comment: OP want only top 1 FIELDS ? it isnt in hes request or i dont see it ... I think, he only wants not nulls for each category from field1...

Comment: You are right! Let's se what is more adherent to OP requirements

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this scenario, it wouldn't happen, that two are not null on same field 2-4 for same field 1. Your query works just fine. Now let's imagine that I have 30 fields and ~1mio rows. Wouldn't all the join make this really unperformant?